# How to overload operator= to return pointer to a member?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Having something like the following code (simplified):

```
struct MyStruct {
    int member1;
    int member2;
};

class MyClass { 
    MyStruct *data;
}


MyClass obj;

// put obj.data in pstruct  
// so obj.data->element1 is the same as pstruct->element1
MyStruct *pstruct = obj;
```

I don't want to create a copy of `obj.data` but return the same pointer so if i make a change in `pstruct->member1` the change is the same in `obj.data->element1` (and the opposite).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Note that your example never invokes `operator=`. Object initialization is different from object assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want a conversion operator that creates a `MyStruct*` from a `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass {
    MyStruct *data;
public:
    operator MyStruct*() {
       return data;
    }
};
```

Comment: I would avoid adding conversions to types whenever possible. Implicit conversions kick in when you want (as in the question) but also when you don't, opening the code to allow for dumb mistakes in code. Suddently `if (obj)` is valid, as is `obj + 5` which are two operations that you might not want and will now be allowed. This is opening a big can of worms...

Comment: @David: I agree, but from the question it's hard to tell what the OP *really* want's to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

No problem.

```
MyClass obj;

MyStruct *pstruct = obj.data;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that you cannot overload operators for pointers, the good thing is that you don't need to, you just need to assign pointers appropriatedly:

```
MyClass obj;
MyStruct *pstruct = obj.data; // Assuming that `data` is accessible here
```

If you don't have access to the internal `data` member, you will need to either provide access (a member function that returns the pointer --breaks encapsulation), or make the calling code a `friend` of `MyClass` to grant access to the internal type (still breaks encapsulation, just a bit less).

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do what you want with a conversion operator, but I'd prefer to see you write a [getter method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessor#C.2B.2B_example). This avoids issues with implicit conversions.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    MyStruct *data;
public:
    MyStruct* GetData() const { return data; }
};


int main () {
  MyClass obj;
  MyStruct *pstruct = obj.GetData();
  MyStruct *pstruct2;
  pstruct = obj.GetData();
}
```